# android : calling an api continuously with delay

Tags: java, android, multithreading, coroutine

i need to call two APIs continuously using retrofit. one should be called every 10 seconds and one should be called every 3 seconds. which one is the most efficient method for this purpose. thread, coroutine, rxjava , ... .

could you please describe each one and it's usage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RxJava is best for this case 
you can use it like this

```
// for 10 sec 
    disposableLiveTracking = Observable.interval(0, 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(v -> call api here, throwable -> throwable.printStackTrace());

/for 3 sec
    disposableLiveTracking = Observable.interval(0, 3, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(v -> call api here, throwable -> throwable.printStackTrace())
```

// you should dispose Rxjava subs in onPause or destroy

like this

```
  @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (null != disposableLiveTracking ) {
            disposableLiveTracking .dispose();
        }
    }
```